# CSS variables are not working on body tag while implementing a dark/light theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am developing two themes for my site (light and dark), the site is developed in React. In the main CSS file I have inserted the colors that should be used in the light theme and in the dark theme, like this:

```
#light{
--color-bg: #4e4f50; /* #1f1f38 */
--color-bg-variant: #746c70; /* #2c2c6c */
--color-primary: #e2ded0; /* #4db5ff */
--color-primary-variant: #647c90; /* rgba(77, 181, 255, 0.4) */
--color-white: white;
--color-light: rgb(255 255 255 / 60%);
}

#dark{
--color-bg: #1A1A2E; /* #1f1f38 */
--color-bg-variant: #16213E; /* #2c2c6c */
--color-primary: #E94560; /* #4db5ff */
--color-primary-variant: #0F3460; /* rgba(77, 181, 255, 0.4) */
--color-white: white;
--color-light: rgb(255 255 255 / 60%);
}
```

These variables are read throughout the project apparently except in the CSS of the `body` tag which is like this:

```
body {
font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
background: var(--color-bg);
color: var(--color-white);
line-height: 1.7; /* distanza tra le macroaree */
background-image: none;
}
```

Rightly, not working, there are all colors, except the background one, so the problem is not ignorable. I don't understand why in all the other CSS the variables are read but not from the `body` tag.

Here is how I use and change the theme from light to dark and vice versa (`App.jsx`):

```
import { createContext } from "react"
import { useState } from "react"

export const ThemeContext = createContext(null)

const App = () => {
const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark")

const toggleTheme = () => {

setTheme((curr) => (curr === "light" ? "dark" : "light"))
}
return (
<ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme, setTheme}}>
  <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={
          <div id={theme}>
            <Header/>
            <Nav/>
            <About/>
            <Experience/>
            <Services/>
            <BlogPreview/>
            <Contact/>
            <Footer/>
          </div>}
        />
        <Route path="/Blog" element={
          <div id={theme}>
            <Blog/>
            <NavG/>
          </div>}  
        />
        <Route path="*" element={
          <div id={theme}>
            <Error/>
            <NavGG/>
          </div>
        }/>
        <Route path="/Blog/buymeanr6please" element={
          <div id={theme}>
            <Post1/>
          </div>
        }/>
      </Routes>
  </Router>
</ThemeContext.Provider>
)
}

export default App
```

I hope I have explained myself well. Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [cascading and inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance) issue. Those CSS variables of yours are defined in the context of that `<div id={theme}>`, which is a child of `body`, so `body` can't see them.

Either move the property from `body` to `<div id={theme}>`, like so:

```
#dark, #dark{
 font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
 background: var(--color-bg);
 color: var(--color-white);
 line-height: 1.7; /* distanza tra le macroaree */
 background-image: none;
}
```

Or sets your variables on `html` so every child, including `body`, can see them. If you decide to do it this way, add the below code in `App.jsx` and remove the `id` from `<div id={theme}>`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   document.documentElement.setAttribute("id", theme);
}, [theme]);
```